# What is "braid Scotch"?

Tags: scotland

A family history mentions that a set of my ancestors in New Brunswick, CANADA, spoke "braid Scotch", but I cannot figure out what that is. There are only a few mentions of the phrase online, but they provide no clear definition.

Comment: Where I live if someone speaks "broad Oldham" (or Lancashire)" it simply means they have a very strong **local** accent

Answer (score 4):

There is technically no such thing as the *Scotch* language, although that term was used historically. It is more commonly referred to as the [Scots language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scots_language).

[Braid](http://www.dsl.ac.uk/entry/snd/braid_adj_adv) Scots (English *broad Scots*) is simply the vernacular (native dialect). This phrase alone does not localise the dialect within Scotland further.

What the author probably meant was: they could hardly understand a word of what they were saying when they spoke in "braid Scotch".

Comment: ...so this is _not_ Scottish Gaelic.

Comment: I had to look up the meaning of "vernacular"; it's domestic or of the people.

Comment: I don't think that he was saying that he couldn't understand them. I think that he was giving a piece of information to describe them more fully. They were from the lowlands/boarders.

Comment: Sorry, I meant that last part a bit tongue-in-cheek – obviously no way to know from this whether he could understand braid Scots

Answer (score 0):

Braid Scots was mostly a mix of old, old English and Scottish Gaelic. The most famed use of braid Scots is written by
John Barbour, a poet from early Britain